# Triangle not visible OpenGLES2.0 android

Tags: android

Hello Guys I am Beginner to OpenGL,
I am Trying to follow android developers tutorials . But I am not able to see the Triangle.
What is wrong;

I tried to create a triangle  on surface created and called draw method inseide onDraw of Renderer class .

Triangle class:

```
public class Triangle {
    private final String vertexShaderCode =
            "attribute vec4 vPosition;" +
            "void main() {" +
            "  gl_Position = vPosition;" +
            "}";
    private final int vertexCount = triangleCoords.length / COORDS_PER_VERTEX;
    private final int vertexStride = COORDS_PER_VERTEX * 4;
    private int mProgram,mPositionHandle,mColorHandle;
        private final String fragmentShaderCode =
            "precision mediump float;" +
            "uniform vec4 vColor;" +
            "void main() {" +
            "  gl_FragColor = vColor;" +
            "}";
    private FloatBuffer vertexBuffer;

    // number of coordinates per vertex in this array
    static final int COORDS_PER_VERTEX = 3;
    static float triangleCoords[] = {   // in counterclockwise order:
             0.0f,  0.622008459f, 0.0f, // top
            -0.5f, -0.311004243f, 0.0f, // bottom left
             0.5f, -0.311004243f, 0.0f  // bottom right
    };

    // Set color with red, green, blue and alpha (opacity) values
    float color[] = { 0.63671875f, 0.76953125f, 0.22265625f, 1.0f };

    public Triangle() {
        // initialize vertex byte buffer for shape coordinates
        ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(
                // (number of coordinate values * 4 bytes per float)
                triangleCoords.length * 4);
        // use the device hardware's native byte order
        bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());

        // create a floating point buffer from the ByteBuffer
        vertexBuffer = bb.asFloatBuffer();
        // add the coordinates to the FloatBuffer
        vertexBuffer.put(triangleCoords);
        // set the buffer to read the first coordinate
        vertexBuffer.position(0);
        int vertexShader = loadShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vertexShaderCode);
        int fragmentShader = loadShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentShaderCode);

        mProgram = GLES20.glCreateProgram();             // create empty OpenGL ES Program
        GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, vertexShader);   // add the vertex shader to program
        GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, fragmentShader); // add the fragment shader to program
        GLES20.glLinkProgram(mProgram);   
    }

    public static int loadShader(int type, String shaderCode){

        // create a vertex shader type (GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER)
        // or a fragment shader type (GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER)
        int shader = GLES20.glCreateShader(type);

        // add the source code to the shader and compile it
        GLES20.glShaderSource(shader, shaderCode);
        GLES20.glCompileShader(shader);

        return shader;
    }

    public void draw() {
        // Add program to OpenGL ES environment
        GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgram);

        // get handle to vertex shader's vPosition member
        mPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "vPosition");

        // Enable a handle to the triangle vertices
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);

        // Prepare the triangle coordinate data
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandle, COORDS_PER_VERTEX,
                                     GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
                                     vertexStride, vertexBuffer);

        // get handle to fragment shader's vColor member
        mColorHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "vColor");

        // Set color for drawing the triangle
        GLES20.glUniform4fv(mColorHandle, 1, color, 0);

        // Draw the triangle
        GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertexCount);

        // Disable vertex array
        GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing code to setup a projection matrix and viewport.  You also need to call glSwapBuffers(), unless you are using GLSurfaceView, which does that for you.  You can use an ortho projection for simplicity, and it should be multiplied by each vPosition in your vertex shader.

This is how you can use and construct a projection matrix:

```
Ortho(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);
glUniformMatrix4fv(iProjectionMatrixLocation, 1, GL_FALSE, (const GLfloat *)&m_mViewProj);
glViewport(0, 0, m_iWidth, m_iHeight);


...

// Construct a matrix for an orthographic projection view.
void Button::Ortho(float left, float top, float right, float bottom, float nearPlane, float farPlane)
{
    float rcplmr = 1.0f / (left - right);
    float rcpbmt = 1.0f / (bottom - top);
    float rcpnmf = 1.0f / (nearPlane - farPlane);

    m_mViewProj.f0 = -2.0f * rcplmr;
    m_mViewProj.f1 = 0.0f;
    m_mViewProj.f2 = 0.0f;
    m_mViewProj.f3 = 0.0f;
    m_mViewProj.f4 = 0.0f;
    m_mViewProj.f5 = -2.0f * rcpbmt;
    m_mViewProj.f6 = 0.0f;
    m_mViewProj.f7 = 0.0f;
    m_mViewProj.f8 = 0.0f;
    m_mViewProj.f9 = 0.0f;
    m_mViewProj.f10 = -2.0f * rcpnmf;
    m_mViewProj.f11 = 0.0f;
    m_mViewProj.f12 = (right + left) * rcplmr;
    m_mViewProj.f13 = (top + bottom) * rcpbmt;
    m_mViewProj.f14 = (nearPlane + farPlane) * rcpnmf;
    m_mViewProj.f15 = 1.0f;
}
```

The third article here will help:

http://montgomery1.com/opengl/